# Java Android Trouble comparing dates

Tags: java, date

My app has the ability to set reminders and all that works fine. The issue is checking whether or not the date the reminder is scheduled for has passed. I have this setup to compare dates. alarm is timeinmillis. Even if the date has passed it says "This note has a reminder scheduled." What am I missing here?

```
        Date currentcal = new Date();
        Date alarmcal = new Date(); 
        alarmcal.setTime(alarm);
        if (alarm != 0) {
            if(alarmcal.compareTo(currentcal)<0) {
                delete_message.setText("This note has a reminder scheduled.");   
            } else if (alarmcal.compareTo(currentcal)>0) {
                delete_message.setText("Reminder date passed.");            
            }                   
        }
```

Comment: what is the time that you are setting?

Comment: What do you mean?  I will set a reminder for a minute later for instance the reminder will go off but the text that a reminder is scheduled will still remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the alarmcal as a Date, not the corresponding long value. Since both "clocks" are alive your logic will fail. The following snippet will set time alarmcal 10 secs ahead of current time. The comparison will always be with a "alive clock".

```
long alarmcal = new Date().getTime() + 10 * 1000; // add 10 seconds from current time
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(alarmcal + " " + new Date().getTime());              
            if (alarmcal >= new Date().getTime()) {
                System.out.println("This note has a reminder scheduled.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Reminder date passed.");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The printout of this will be:

293484130625 1293484124628
This note has a reminder scheduled.
1293484130625 1293484126628
This note has a reminder scheduled.
1293484130625 1293484128628
This note has a reminder scheduled.
1293484130625 1293484130629
Reminder date passed.
1293484130625 1293484132629
Reminder date passed.
1293484130625 1293484134629
Reminder date passed.

Hopefully you can adopt this to your android code

Comment: I think I found the problem. I'm saving alarm as type integer. Is there anyway to fix this without messing with database column type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your logic switched. Your first if statement is actuallychecking to see if alarmcal is less than the current date, and your else if is actually checking if the alarmcal is in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
       if(alarmcal.before(new Date()))
             delete_message.setText("Reminder date passed."); 
       else
             delete_message.setText("This note has a reminder scheduled.");
```

Hope you are setting `alarmcal.setTime` correctly.

---

OK so the above code works. You may be setting time wrong. see here

```
   Date alarmcal = new Date();
   //alarmcal.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - 5000); //print date passed
alarmcal.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000); //prints reminder scheduled
   if(alarmcal.before(new Date()))
         System.out.println("Reminder date passed."); 
   else
       System.out.println("This note has a reminder scheduled.");
```

Comment: alarm is a Timeinmillis. BTW, doing this it always says Reminder date passed. =\

Comment: try this set `alarm = System.currentTimeInMillis() + 5000` this way you will test whether logic work. And then  again test with `alarm = System.currentTimeInMillis() - 5000` see if you are getting opposite results